# Prorammatically created Layout crashes the app in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I have set my layout to an `xml` which has `ExpandableListView` as root.
Since, a scrollable view can't be put (or is very complex to put) inside another scrollable view, I have decided to put all the views I need alongside the `ExpandableListView` as its `headers` and `footers`.

In my `header`, I have put 3-4 small `LinearLayouts` each having 1-2 `TextViews`.
Everything works fine until here.

Now, in my `footer`, I want to add a `ListView` like view, having about 3-4 `strings`. Because I do not know the size of list, I decided to make the view programmatically.

When I include this view, the app stops working when:

1. Orientation is changed from `Portrait` to `Landscape`
2. Layout is tried to open in `Landscape` mode

So, basically `Landscape` mode doesn't work well, but I don't know why?

Here is my code:

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)

        val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sd, container, false)
        val expView = myView.findViewById<ExpandableListView>(R.id.sd_exp)!!
        val expAdapter = AdapterEV(activity!!, myData)
        expView.setAdapter(expAdapter)
        expView.setOnChildClickListener { /* handling child click */ }

        // example how I add view in header
        val hView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sd_h1, container, false)
        hView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sd_h1).text = myString
        expView.addHeaderView(hView)

        // now here is the problem
        val fView = setListView(myList, inflater, container)
        expView.addFooterView(fView)

        return myView
    }

    private fun setListView(myList: ArrayList<String>, inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): View {
        val rootLayout = LinearLayout(activity)
        rootLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        rootLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        // removing the below for loop doesn't help
        for (i in 0 until myList.size) {
            val childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sd_f1, container, false)
            // even below lines don't work in place of above line
            // val childView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.sd_f1, null)
            // val childView = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.sd_f1, rootLayout, true)
            childView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sd_f1_t1).text = "${i+1}"
            childView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sd_f1_t2).text = myList[i]
            rootLayout.addView(childView)
        }

        return rootLayout
    }

}
```

The `sd.xml` file having `ExpandableListView` is:

```xml
<ExpandableListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sd_exp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

And the layout `sd_f1.xml` I am including in `setListView` is:

```xml
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sd_f1_t1" />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sd_f1_t2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---EDIT---

logcat error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
        at android.widget.ListView.removeUnusedFixedViews(ListView.java:2070)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1931)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2198)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:903)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20715)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6202)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2802)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2329)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1469)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7209)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1050)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:862)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:797)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1036)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Have you checked the logcat for exception stack trace?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have updated the question with it.

Comment: Sounds like `LinearLayout.LayoutParams(` should be `AbsListView.LayoutParams`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes it worked, you may post it as an answer if you like to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your stack trace,

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams(` should be `AbsListView.LayoutParams(`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use context from container received in onCreateView instead of Activity when Instantiate LinearLayout

Comment: I don't know how to do that exactly, but I have tried to replace `LinearLayout(activity)` with `LinearLayout(context)` and also with `LinearLayout(container!!.context)`, but none of these changes helped.